# when and why it will automatically add gloved hand mouse to an element while we hover over the element

Tags: html, css

I did not find the answer in SO.

1. Do we need to explicitly add `cursor: pointer;` to have gloved hand mouse?
2. when it will automatically add gloved hand mouse to an element while we hover over the element? I mean what kinds of elements we hover will have gloved hand mouse.
3. I also want to know why it will add gloved hand mouse to an element while we hover over the element?
4. How can we disable gloved hand mouse which is supposed to be becoming gloved hand mouse when we hover an element (Just for a specified element)? And any solution to disable all gloved hand mouse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### In short:

- `<a>`  tags are generally the only element that have `cursor: pointer;` by default.
- Applying `cursor: pointer;` to other elements will give them the "hand" cursor.
- Similarly, applying `pointer: default;` will apply the standard "arrow" cursor.

---

### Breakdown by question:

> 1. Do we need to explicitly add cursor: pointer; to have gloved hand mouse?

If the element does not have it as the default cursor, then yes.

---

> 2. when it will automatically add gloved hand mouse to an element while we hover over the element? I mean what kinds of elements we hover will have gloved hand mouse.

It differs from browser-to-browser, but for the most part, `<a>` tags *(with an `href` attribute)* are the only that have `cursor: pointer;` as the default cursor. Per the [W3 specification on cursors](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#cursor):

> **links and status cursors**
>
> *The cursor is a pointer that indicates a link.*

---

> 3. I also want to know why it will add gloved hand mouse to an element while we hover over the element?

This question seems the same as the previous. If the element is a link, or has `cursor: pointer;` applied, then it will have the "gloved hand mouse" cursor.

---

> 4. How can we disable gloved hand mouse which is supposed to be becoming gloved hand mouse when we hover an element (Just for a specified element)? And any solution to disable all gloved hand mouse

Simply tell the element to use `cursor: default;` instead.

```css
a {
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">No pointer.</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If it doesn't have it, then yes (exceptions below).
2. Links (< a >...) will get cursor: pointer automatically.
3. It adds because it's the default value. "pointer:
   The cursor is a pointer that indicates a link." from [w3.org](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/ui.html#propdef-cursor)
4. Set cursor: default for the specified item or anything else you want. You can find cursor options on the link above. You can disable it on all links with a{ cursor: default; }.